# Java i18n without RessourceBundle

Tags: java, internationalization

I am trying to get the `i18n` properties file out of my `BuildPath`. If you are trying to get the `PropertiesFile` the `ResourceBundle.getBundle`will throw a `java.util.MissingResourceException`. Is there a method to load `i18n` files from outside the `BuildPath`but still has the comfort of detecting your locale?

EDIT:

Here is the solution I was able to create with the Help of [Paweł Dyda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421051/1548788). Maybe somebody will need it. Probably there could be some improvements made, but it works ;)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle.Control;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class GlobalConfigurationProvider {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalConfigurationProvider.class);

    private static GlobalConfigurationProvider instance;

    PropertiesConfiguration i18n;


    private GlobalConfigurationProvider() {
        String path = GlobalConfigurationProvider.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = "";
        try {
            decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
            // This ugly thing is needed to get the correct
            // Path
            File f = new File(decodedPath);
            f = f.getParentFile().getParentFile();
            decodedPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.logger.error("Failed to decode the Jar path", e);
        }
        this.logger.debug("The Path of the jar is: " + decodedPath);

        String configFolder = FilenameUtils.concat(decodedPath, "cfg");
        String i18nFolder = FilenameUtils.concat(configFolder, "i18n");
        File i18nFile = null;
        try {
            i18nFile = this.getFileForLocation(new File(i18nFolder), Locale.getDefault());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.logger.error("Can't find the LocaleFile", e);
        }
        if (!i18nFile.exists()) {
            // If this can't be found something is wrong
            i18nFile = new File(i18nFolder, "eng.i18n");
            if (!i18nFile.exists()) {
                this.logger.error("Can't find the i18n File at the Location: " + i18nFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        this.logger.debug("The Path to the i18n File is: " + i18nFile);

        try {
            this.i18n = new PropertiesConfiguration(i18nFile);
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            this.logger.error("Couldn't Initialize the i18nPropertiesFile", e);
        }
    }

    private File getFileForLocation(File i18nFolder, Locale locale) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Control control = Control.getControl(Control.FORMAT_DEFAULT);
        List<Locale> locales = control.getCandidateLocales(this.getBaseName(), locale);
        File f = null;
        for (Locale l : locales) {
            String i18nBundleName = control.toBundleName(this.getBaseName(), l);
            String i18nFileName = control.toResourceName(i18nBundleName, "properties");
            f = new File(i18nFolder, i18nFileName);
            this.logger.debug("Looking for the i18n File at: " + f);
            if (f.exists()) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        // Last try for a File that should exist
        if (!locale.equals(Locale.US)) {
            return this.getFileForLocation(i18nFolder, Locale.US);
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't find any i18n Files in the Folder " + i18nFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private String getBaseName() {
        // TODO: Get this from the Settings later
        return "messages";
    }

    public static GlobalConfigurationProvider getInstance() {
        if (GlobalConfigurationProvider.instance == null) {
            GlobalConfigurationProvider.instance = new GlobalConfigurationProvider();
        }
        return GlobalConfigurationProvider.instance;
    }

    public String getI18nString(String key) {
        try {
            return this.i18n.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `PropertyReader` but by doing that you will not achive I18N.

Comment: Yes I know I could use it like a regular properties file. But for me it is important, that it gets the locale automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there are methods to do that. Anyway, I believe your problem is the wrong path to the resource you are trying to load.

Nonetheless, for sure you are looking the way to use Locale fall-back mechanism to load very specific resource. It can be done. You may want to take a look at [ResourceBundle.Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) class. For example you can get the list of fall-back locales:

```
Control control = Control.getControl(Control.FORMAT_DEFAULT);
List<Locale> locales = control.getCandidateLocales("messages",
           Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-TW"));
```

From there, you can actually create names of the resource files you are looking for:

```
for (Locale locale : locales) {
      String bundleName = control.toBundleName("messages", locale);
      String resourceName = control.toResourceName(bundleName, "properties");
      // break if resource under given name exist
}
```

Then, you need to load the resource somehow - you may want to use [ClassLoader's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) [getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to open the `InputStream` for you. The last step could be actually use the stream as an input to [PropertyResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html):

```
ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(inputStream);
```

You can alternatively pass a [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) rather than `InputStream`, which has at least one advantage - you may actually allow properties file to be encoded in UTF-8, rather than regular ISO8859-1.

Comment: I think this won't work if the properties file isn't on the build path?

Comment: @Robin: Because you can pass an arbitrary `InputStream` or `Reader` to PropertyResourceBundle, it really does not matter where properties file is. You probably cannot load it with `ClassLoader`, but again you don't have to. BTW. you can use [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) to read from arbitrary Jar file wherever it is placed.

Comment: Ok now I get your answer. This is a probably a very good idea! Unfortunately I can't try it right now. But I will totally try it, because it seems better than my actual solution.